# Spring-kafka error handling with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement error handling in Spring boot kafa. In my Kafka listener I am throwing a runtime exception as per below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics= "Kafka-springboot-example", groupId="group-employee-json")
    public void consumeEmployeeJson(Employee employee) {
        logger.info("Consumed Employee JSON: "+ employee);

        if(null==employee.getEmployeeId()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
            //throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("failed");
        }
    }
```

And I have configured error handling as per below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> containerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template){

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory= new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template)));

        return factory;

    }
}
```

And my listener for DLT is as per below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics= "Kafka-springboot-example.DLT", groupId="group-employee-json")
    public void consumeEmployeeErrorJson(Employee employee) {
        logger.info("Consumed Employee JSON frpm DLT topic: "+ employee);
    }
```

But my message is not getting published to DLT topic.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edited:

application.properties

```
server.port=8088

#kafka-producer-config
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer


#Kafka consumer properties
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group-employee-json
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
```

Comment: Show your `application.properties/yml`. Do you have `...consumer.auto-offset-reset: earliest`?  Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.kafka` to see if it provides any clues. Edit the question; don't add code/config in a comment.

Comment: application.properties

Comment: I meant the contents; but see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> containerFactory(`

If you use a non-standard bean name for the container factory, you need to set it on the `@KafkaListener` in the `containerFactory` property.

The default bean name is `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` which is auto-configured by Boot. You need to either override that bean or configure the listener to point to your non-standard bean name.